# Exit status 1 error while installing mod_wsgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, mod-wsgi

I am getting following error while installing `mod_wsgi` using `pip3`. I downloaded it once mistakenly before installing Apache, then it threw error for Apache's unavailability and didn't install. Then I installed Apache using command `brew install apache2` and then did `pip3 install mod_wsgi --no-cache-dir` so that it don't take up the cached image, but it didn't work and got following error. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
    Collecting mod_wsgi
  Downloading mod_wsgi-4.7.1.tar.gz (498 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 498 kB 4.6 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0f/3wwtkx4d6m94zpmq0r5rw5c80000gn/T/pip-install-lygp82k1/mod-wsgi_ef198f9a817445a7b3cf53dd590fbdb2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0f/3wwtkx4d6m94zpmq0r5rw5c80000gn/T/pip-install-lygp82k1/mod-wsgi_ef198f9a817445a7b3cf53dd590fbdb2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/0f/3wwtkx4d6m94zpmq0r5rw5c80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-2q3u8hgc
         cwd: /private/var/folders/0f/3wwtkx4d6m94zpmq0r5rw5c80000gn/T/pip-install-lygp82k1/mod-wsgi_ef198f9a817445a7b3cf53dd590fbdb2/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/0f/3wwtkx4d6m94zpmq0r5rw5c80000gn/T/pip-install-lygp82k1/mod-wsgi_ef198f9a817445a7b3cf53dd590fbdb2/setup.py", line 490, in <module>
        target_version = tuple(map(int, target.split('.')))
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Seems you did some wrong things: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/setup.py#L495 i strongly suggest to remove everything related to apache on your mac and reinstall or use docker container instead of messing with your system. Otherwise try to override the environnement variable but good luck with this

Comment: Certainly I would have, it would be great if you could please enlighten me on this. @ConstantinGuidon

Comment: i'm not an expert but seems it comes from your python install:


`A Python distribution contains a Makefile and a pyconfig.h header file that are necessary to build both the Python binary itself and third-party C extensions compiled using distutils.

sysconfig puts all variables found in these files in a dictionary that can be accessed using get_config_vars() or get_config_var().`
source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#configuration-variables